# ng-if and google tag manager script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-tag-manager

my question is regarding the Google Tag Manager, and only running the script if certain conditions are satisfied.

This is the code I have:

```
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <div ng-if="status === 'true'">
        <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-****"
        height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
        <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','*****');</script>
    </div>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

This code doesnt work, but I am wondering how to use `ng-if` to run this code if certain conditions are fulfilled. Or perhaps I should take another approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would check, if `status` actually is of type string, since you are using `===`. Try either `==` or `use === true`.

Your usage of `ng-if` as directive is correct.

I assume the script fires before Angular is loaded. It might be necessary to put the script inside a controller or directive and fire it, when `status` is `true`.

If you can access `status` from Javascript outside Angular (as global variable e.g.), then you can embrace your TagManager-script  like this:

```
<div>
    <script>
        if (status == true) {
            // Google Tag Manager IIFE goes here.
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue isnt whether or not it is a string, as that is actually a dummy value for this question. I believe that the script still gets fired, as it is javascript so it appears that it is irrelevant that the div is hidden... is this the case?

Comment: The idea behind ng-if is not to hide the div, but to not render it at all. Your script actually shouldn't show up in the DOM. But thinking about it, I assume, that the script fires, BEFORE Angular itself is loaded, so you might be better off putting your script inside a controller or a directive and just use that to load the google tag manager. Alternatively try embracing the script with an if - statement itself.

Comment: That is what I was thinking to put it in a controller. That probably makes more sense. Also, I will try using the script with ng-if. Was just wondering if there was something I was unaware of to prevent the script from firing. Thanks for your help